# links for firebug on Internet Explorer

Tags: asp.net

i want to install firebug on IE.can you give me the links for free download of firebug

Answer (score 2):

You could use 
[firebug lite](http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite). That works on IE (6+).

Answer (score 1):

Firebug is firefox addin and you cannot install it on IE. IE Developer tools are the closest you will get to Firebug for IE.

There is something called [Firebug Lite](http://getfirebug.com/releases/lite/latest/) which works on IE.

Answer (score 0):

this is the IE developer toolbar link http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=95e06cbe-4940-4218-b75d-b8856fced535 as firebug cannot be installed to IE

Answer (score 0):

Firebug is free, but however is not designed for use with IE, it's actually a Firefox addon (Hence the name), if you want to get it for firefox (I highly reccomend this) then you can get it from:

GetFireBug.Com

However, if you want a decent equivelant for use within IE, firebug lite is a script based version you can use on your pages to give you the same inspection capabillities from any browser you choose, more [Here](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/install-firebug-for-browsers-other-than-firefox/)